# Getting active record based on column value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database table named BusinessAssociate and in that table for the sake of complexity there are 2 columns

```
BusinessAssociateKey int
AmalgamatedIntoBAKey int
```

Using the BusinessAssociateKey we can join on other tables, and one of those tables (BACorporateStatus) tells us if that BusinessAssociate is active or amalgamated.

Let's assume that Business Associate key 123456 is amalgamated into BA Key 987654, in the same table there will be a row, with a BusinessAssociateKey of 987654, and this row may well be amalgamated too, for example into BusinessAssociateKey 283746.

Is there a way on a per BusinessAssociateKey to find the active (not amalgamated) Business Associate?

The number of chains is unknown, could be none or could be n.

Edit: Here is a SQL Fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e886/1 and in this example BusinessAssociateKey 56781 is not amalgamated, so for BusinessAssociateKey 123 the surviving/active BA Key is 56781.

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join with the table. Here I have added row number to get last records using self join.

```
   Select  F.Nbr, F.BusinessAssociateKey, F.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey
    From
   (Select row_number() Over(order by (select 1)) as Nbr, E.BusinessAssociateKey, E.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey
    From BusinessAssociate E
   ) F
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (Select row_number() Over(order by (select 1)) as Nbr, E.BusinessAssociateKey, E.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey
    From BusinessAssociate E
   ) K
   ON  F.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey = K.BusinessAssociateKey
   where K.Nbr IS  NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88b53/26

Comment: Close, but the result I want is the original BusinessAssociateKey (123) and I want the AmalgamatedIntoBAKey to be 56781

Answer (score -1):

Recursion:

```
;with rec_cte as(
select b1.BusinessAssociateKey, b1.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey, 1 as rn
  from BusinessAssociate b1 left outer join BusinessAssociate b2 on b1.BusinessAssociateKey = b2.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey
  where b2.BusinessAssociateKey is null
union all
select c.BusinessAssociateKey, b.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey, c.rn + 1
  from rec_cte c inner join BusinessAssociate b on c.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey = b.BusinessAssociateKey
  where b.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey is not null),
cte as(
select BusinessAssociateKey, max(rn) as rn
  from rec_cte
  group by BusinessAssociateKey)

select r.BusinessAssociateKey, r.AmalgamatedIntoBAKey
  from rec_cte r inner join cte c on r.BusinessAssociateKey = c.BusinessAssociateKey and r.rn = c.rn
  option (maxdop 0)
```

Comment: Right but if you look at the fiddle lets say my business asociate key is 123, I want to 'walk down' the chain and get the last active BA Key